# Remove Control Characters out of a string

Tags: c++, string, data-manipulation, esp32

I have a string given, which contains the following content (so the following lines are stored in a String-variable):

```
S*⸮
------------------------
K!
NAG                00.10
K"
NMAGICSTAR 2 L    V1.0-1
K#
AUFSTELLORT:  S 00000000
K$
GERAET NR.:   0000000000
KC
ZULASSUNGS NR.:411107770
K)
BAUART:          NAG5A02
K(
ABLAUFDATUM:     2021/04
------------------------
```

Can anyone help me or give me a short hint how to remove the control codes (so the `S*⸮` respectively the `K!`) out of this string (there is always a small rectangle before the control code, i don't know why it is removed)? So that in the end, it's

```
------------------------
NAG                00.10
NMAGICSTAR 2 L    V1.0-1
AUFSTELLORT:  S 00000000
GERAET NR.:   0000000000
ZULASSUNGS NR.:411107770
BAUART:          NAG5A02
ABLAUFDATUM:     2021/04
------------------------
```

Let me finally quote something out of the documentation, maybe it helps:

> Each line is max. 24 characters long and must end with LF [0Ah]

> Control Code "ESC 'S' 21h LF" means: XON Startsequence with manufacturer code, machine code and dataset code

I am trying to do this whole task on an ESP32/ Arduino IDE (C++).

Comment: So you want to split the string by newlines, remove odd lines, put it back together?

Comment: For C++ search for "how to split a string", if you want C, you probably have to walk the string using something like `strtok` and copy the bits you want to keep into another string.

Comment: Show a hex dump of the original string.

Comment: Hello and thank you both so much for your answers… Yes, absolutely correct, if that's possible in C++, that would be the goal. Sorry that I have to reask, but how to get the hex dump of the original string?^^ Best greetings

Answer (score 0):

This is not an anwser. You may use the following code to print you string as integer in hex form. Every 12 characters a wide separation, and every 24 a new line. The arrange makes easier for you to count 24 characters.

```
#include <iostream>
void dump_str(const std::string&str)
{
    int n;
    std::cout << std::hex;

    for (int i=0; i<str.size(); i++)
      {
          n = str[i];
          if (i%24==0) std::cout << std::endl;
             else if (i%12 == 0 ) std::cout <<"  ";
          if (n<16) std::cout << " " << '0' << n;
          else  std::cout << " " << n;
       }
}
int main ()
{
  std::string str ( "some\r\ttest\rst\2\athis is \n a ran\5dom\10g\n\nTake this for granted. To bo or not to be\a\a\t\t");
  dump_str(str);
}
```

Print-out of this example:(meaning of the number can be checked in an ascii table google search.)

```
73 6f 6d 65 0d 09 74 65 73 74 0d 73  74 02 07 74 68 69 73 20 69 73 20 0a
20 61 20 72 61 6e 05 64 6f 6d 08 67  0a 0a 54 61 6b 65 20 74 68 69 73 20
66 6f 72 20 67 72 61 6e 74 65 64 2e  20 54 6f 20 62 6f 20 6f 72 20 6e 6f
74 20 74 6f 20 62 65 07 07 09 09
```

Send you string to above function dum_str(string), and copy the resultant table appending to your post.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to split the string at \r and \n characters. This way you can iterate each line separately.

```
    void str_split(const std::string& in,  std::vector<std::string>& out, const std::string& delim=" \t\r\n")
    {
        std::string::size_type firstPos = in.find_first_not_of(delim);
        std::string::size_type secondPos = in.find_first_of(delim, firstPos);
        out.clear();
        if(firstPos != std::string::npos)
            out.push_back( in.substr( firstPos, secondPos - firstPos ) );
        while( secondPos != std::string::npos )
        {
            firstPos = in.find_first_not_of(delim, secondPos);
            if(firstPos == std::string::npos)
                break;
            secondPos = in.find_first_of( delim, firstPos );
            out.push_back( in.substr( firstPos, secondPos - firstPos ) );
        }
    }
```